# ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 104

Tags: mysql

I am trying to setup mysql on ubuntu server 17.04 so i can access it remotely.

Currently it is up and running, i can access it locally or if i SSH in first, but when i try to connect using `mysql -h <ip> -u <admin> -p` on my linux mint machine.

It gives me `ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 104`

Here is my /etc/mysql/my.cnf

`[mysqld]
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
skip-name-resolve`

I currently have my firewall off on both machines

my user is `CREATE USER '<username>'@'%' AS IDENTIFIED BY '<Password>'`

I have rebooted the server multiple times, restarted the service, havent gotten it to work yet.

I have also tried to connect using HeidiSQL on my windows machine, i get the same error.

Not sure what else to try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an issue with internal port blockage

Comment: Could you elaborate on this if still possible? What was the exact issue and how was this found? Thank you.

Comment: what's that? can you please explain a bit??